# Anchor com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho este código:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Que funciona como anchor, fazendo com que meu menu me leve a uma determinada parte do site, no caso selecionado pela div. Enfim, um código normal para anchor. Preciso que esse código me leve á 110px acima da div selecionada, acho que fui claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nessa parte:

`scrollTop: target.offset().top`

Coloque:

`scrollTop: target.offset().top - 110`

Comment: Perefito, muito obrigado pela resposta! +1

Comment: Eu que agradeço. Copiei seu código. Estava precisando de um que funcionasse em todos os browsers.

Comment: ahhahah ótimo então!